# Are there any existent military orders?

Tags: religious-orders

The [Knights Templar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Templar) (Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon) are an example of a Christian military order, but were dissolved in the 14th century. Are there any currently existing Christian military orders?

Comment: What research have you done? Is there anything the Wikipedia article on military orders doesn't answer for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Knights of Malta** also known as the Hospitallers of St. John of Jerusalem is a Military Order that still exists.

> The most important of all the military orders, both for the extent of its area and for its duration. It is said to have existed before the Crusades and is not extinct at the present time. During this long career it has not always borne the same name. Known as Hospitallers of Jerusalem until 1309, the members were called Knights of Rhodes from 1309 till 1522, and have been called Knights of Malta since 1530.
>
> In times of war, since 1870, the order has been devoted to ambulance service on the field of battle. [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07477a.htm)

A short [HISTORY OF THE KNIGHTS OF MALTA](http://www.knightsofmalta.com/history/history.html) is an excellent read.

[image: Fra’ Giacomo Dalla Torre del Tempio di Sanguinetto]

> [Fra’ Giacomo Dalla Torre del Tempio di Sanguinetto](https://www.orderofmalta.int/2017/04/30/fra-giacomo-dalla-torre-takes-oath/), elected Lieutenant of the Grand Master of the Sovereign Order of Malta yesterday, has sworn oath today(April 30, 2017) in the Church of Santa Maria in Aventino, before the Council Complete of State (the elective body of the Order of Malta) and Archbishop Angelo Becciu, the Pope’s Special Delegate.

Comment: The [Order of Brothers of the German House of Saint Mary in Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teutonic_Order) is also extant, too, though they've lost their military character in 1929, it seems.

Comment: This is a good answer. Does their current role still include any military functions? The first quote says they have performed ambulance service on the battlefield since 1870 (which would definitely count), but is this still the case in 2017?

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo At present, they still serve as ambulance services in times of war at the discretion of the Pope. "The Order fulfils its institutional tasks especially by carrying out hospitaller works, including social and health assistance, as well as aiding victims of exceptional disasters and of war, attending also to their spiritual well-being and the strengthening of their faith in God." - [CONSTITUTIONAL CHARTER  AND CODE OF  THE SOVEREIGN MILITARY ORDER OF MALTA](https://www.orderofmalta.int/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Sovereign-Order-of-Malta-Constitutional-Charter-and-code.pdf)

Comment: Does the swiss guard that protects the pope counted as a military christian order?

Comment: @RichardThomas The Swiss Guards are not a Military Order  because the members of the Swiss Guards do a Military Service of protecting the Pope for two years which may be renewed. In order to be a Religious Order (military or otherwise) members must profess vows, whereas the Swiss guards are simply sworn into the service of protecting the Pope.